# most efficient way of preserving the leading blanks of sprintf output

Tags: javascript, jquery, printf

Given the following code which works:

```
for (i=0; i<nLinears; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<nLinearPts[i]-1; j++) {
        $wb.upLinearLoad.append('<div>' + sprintf("%5s%8.1f to%7.1f%8.1f"
        ,sLinearSegName[i][j],fLinearPtBA[i][j],fLinearPtBA[i][j+1],fLen)
        .replace(/ /g,"&nbsp;"));
    }
}
```

This ensures that as the numbers change from small (more leading spaces) to large (fewer leading spaces), the column spacing will be maintained. However, as I understand it, using the regular expression for the .replace is not efficient, and as I have this kind of structure throughout the application, I need to have it run as fast as possible.

I believe that jQuery .text() will take care my need, but I also need to .append() the .text() result, and I can't figure out how to make them work together.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could update the `sprintf()` function to output non-breaking spaces in the first place. But have you actually found a performance problem using a regex `.replace()`? I don't think you'll have a problem. Given that you seem to have tabular data, why don't you use a `<table>`? (By the way, I think you're missing a closing parenthesis before the semicolon.)

Comment: Thanks for catching the missing paren. I had truncated the actual much longer statement for purposes of asking the question and accidentally took out the needed paren. I use tables in other places to take care of the problem, but I've heard that they too carry a high overhead. However, I'm not at all sure tables or the regex are a real performance problem. Later I'll probably try a number of things to speed it up, but for the moment I'm trying to get it done and only casually trying to keep it from being too slow. I think I'll take a quick look at the sprintf code. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I looked at sprintf() and found that a simple one-statement change to substitute '&nbsp;' for the pad character insertion got me what I needed.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham - I've added my earlier comment as an answer, since that's what Terry seems to have gone with. Your suggestion is good though, given that any padding-based formatting is going to rely on a fixed-width font anyway.

Comment: Done, and thanks for the info. Obviously I'm still feeling my way around StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could update the `sprintf()` function to output non-breaking spaces in the first place.

But have you actually found a performance problem using a regex `.replace()`? I don't think you'll have a problem. Given that you seem to have tabular data, why don't you use a `<table>`? This is what tables are for.

Answer (score 0):

You could [put these in `<pre>` elements](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) instead of string-replacing `&nbsp;` repeatedly.

This would (usually) format them with a fixed-width font and preserve spaces without any extra work.  The `<pre>` is for preformatted text, which makes sense for what you have here.

If this doesn't work perfectly and you need alternatives, you could [check out this question about how to use pre-formatted text in different contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at sprintf() and found that a simple one-statement change produced what I needed:

```
pad_character = '&nbsp;';
```

My thanks to the author of the sprintf() implementation for using meaningful variable names.