# Twitter Bootstrap - Explanation of the Customization Page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

If you go to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html you can customize Twitter-Bootstrap's css & js files to only include what you need.

However, I don't really understand things like "Code and pre" and have no idea if I need it or not.  Is there a resource that goes over the properties of each checkbox option so I have a better idea if I should include it or not?

Comment: `Code and Pre` is for styling source code stuff inside css. But I don't know if there is a resource that describes it better

Comment: This is an example that talks about things like `<code>` & `<pre>` tags http://twitter-bootstrap.node1.zygote.cc/ or just check them out individually here [**code tags/pre tags**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a resource for that, try downloading only the sections that you have concerns about and inspect them.

about CODE and PRE:

[<code> vs <pre> vs <samp> for inline and block code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets)

So that check box is for specific styles for these text elements.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing - downloading each section and going over t.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

have no idea? you can download all component! http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip