# html syntax to display literal string

Tags: literals

I was reseraching

https://www.google.com.au/#q=html+syntax+to+display+literal+string

Where in a html report is could have strings being displayed literally WITHOUT being processed / converted, e.g. say you wanted to document

is equal to

I was hoping there was a "from here to there" syntax which meant what text was in between was not interperted, even if it had  etceta in it.

Thank in advance

Comment: Lookup PRE HTML tag.
You might also want to take a look there: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065677/what-is-difference-between-pre-and-code-html-tag

Comment: excellent, thanks
p.s. i had examples but they seem to have been goobled, as html did not like them..

Comment: Hmm  i added 
<pre>
<xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
is equal to - pre sample 
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</pre>

<code>
<xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
is equal to - code sample
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</code>

the html was clear but the displayed text in visual studio and another html editor showed

"is equal to - pre sample"
 "is equal to - code sample"

So it seems that these tags do not always display the content.