# How to set codes in html page?

Tags: html

I am new in html and i'm making a html page in which i want to display some code, but it not showing proper way like what we are writing in notepad. So, i have to write each and every line 
 or any other solution is there. Suppose this is the code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.liste);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // Setup the list view
    final ListView prestListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final prestationAdapterEco prestationAdapterEco = new prestationAdapterEco(this, R.layout.prestation);

    prestListView.setAdapter(prestationAdapterEco);

    // Populate the list, through the adapter
    for(final prestationEco entry : getPrestations()) {
        prestationAdapterEco.add(entry);
    }
    prestListView.setClickable(true);
    prestListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Object o = prestListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String str=(String)o;//As you are using Default String Adapter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and i want to show it on html page like this only. Please help.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre><code> code... </code></pre>
```

This seems to be the best method they've found here: [<code> vs <pre> vs <samp> for inline and block code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets#4611735)

It also happens to be the recommended way to [show a sample of computer code on W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element).

Comment: This is not what OP looking for. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065677/what-is-difference-between-pre-and-code-html-tag for reference.

Comment: @Surya edited to be more relevant to the OP question.

Comment: Yup, makes sense now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for code/syntax highlighting in HTML pages. Unfortunately there is no highlighting feature using tags in HTML.

In HTML You can use:

```
<code>You code goes here..</code>
```

For more reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_code.asp and the list of global attributes `code` tag supports: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp

However, you can make use of some javascripts which enables syntaxt highlighting in HTML.

You can check this thread: "[Syntax highlighting code with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160694/syntax-highlighting-code-with-javascript)" for more info.