# Bootstrap new lines in <code>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When trying to show code in `<code>`, the new lines showed as spaces/tabs.

Here's what I input:

```
[code]k
i
l
m
[/code]
```

*(Except `<>` instead of `[]`)*

And here's what I get as output:

```
k i l m
```

I've tried inserting it with JS using `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n`.

Comment: what is the code to output `k i l m`

Comment: maybe `<br>` will suite you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<pre>` tag instead of `<code>` tag.
Check also [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065677/what-is-difference-between-pre-and-code-html-tag)

Comment: I’d say, not necessarily “instead”, but perhaps rather “around”. `<pre><code>…</code></pre>` would make sense, if the content was actual “code” in some way.

Comment: Yeah, especially if he has some kind of styling applied to code.