# Does any assistive technologies consider <kbd>, <samp> and <code> tags differently?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, screen-readers, accessibility

I have been reading about the difference between `kbd`, `samp` and `code` elements. I read about them on MDN and the following two posts:

- [What is difference between <pre> and <code> HTML Tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065677/what-is-difference-between-pre-and-code-html-tag)
- [<code> vs <pre> vs <samp> for inline and block code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets)

Basically `kbd` represents computer input, `samp` represents computer output and `code` represents programming language code. E.g. consider the following HTML paragraph:

> `<p>` I typed `<kbd> Hell yeah Blast </kbd>` in cmd. The computer ran the code `<code> console.log("Run! blasting in 30 secs..."); delay(30000); blastPC(); </code>` and the cmd printed `<samp>`*`Run! blasting in 30 secs...`* `</samp>`.  `</p>`

The input is in `kbd` tags, the programming code is in `code` tags and computer output is in `samp` tags. Everything is fine. My question is:

If I just use `samp` tag in place of `kbd` and `code` tags would it make any difference to assistive technologies like screen readers? Would any assistive technology (more specifically screen readers) pronounce the content in `samp` tag differently from `kbd` content?

Would any web browser render their corresponding contents on screen differently?

P.S: If the question is too broad as per stackoverflow rules then my question is only for screen reader not any other assistive technmology.

Comment: That’s a pretty broad question. There are countless assistive technologies, including customizable ones (e.g., those that allow user settings per HTML element).

Comment: @unor I've changed the question to ask for if anyone knows about about any specific assistive technology that takes `kbd`, `samp` and `code` tags differently. If it is still too broad then plz answer only for scree reader.

Comment: Apart from countless assistive technologies in existence, I'd also argue a problem with this question is that the answer *may* change as they move on and progress. It's a good question IMO, but not really fit for a website which encourages exact, concrete answers.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, I fear this might be a case of a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - would highly recommend you be more specific on what exactly you're trying to do and what made ask this in the first place (if it weren't mere curiosity). Regardless on whether any browsers or assistive technologies display them differently, you should (normally) have semantic markup and use these tags where appropriate.

Comment: @fstanis There is nothing X Y about the question. It arose of mere curisoty that why would w3c have made three different tags which have same output. I just want to see what is the practical difference in `samp`, `kbd` and `code`. Web browsers have no practical difference for these tags. Are these tags identical in every device/technology?