# HTML tag that causes other tags to be rendered as plain text

Tags: html

I'd like to add an area to a page where all of the dynamic content is rendered as plain text instead of markup. For example:

```
  <myMagicTag>
      <b>Hello</b> World
  </myMagicTag>
```

I want the `<b>` tag to show up as just text and not as a bold directive. I'd rather not have to write the code to convert every "<" to an "`&lt;`".

I know that `<textarea>` will do it, but it has other undesirable side effects like adding scroll bars.

Does myMagicTag exist?

*Edit:* A jQuery or javascript function that does this would also be ok. Can't do it server-side, unfortunately.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets

Comment: You could put it in a <noscript> element, and then via JavaScript grab it, HTML encode it and paste it into a DIV on the page. <noscript> ensures that it won't be parsed, executed, etc.

Answer (score 17):

You can do this with the [`script` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) (bolded by me):

> The `script` element allows authors to include dynamic script and **data blocks** in their documents.

Example:

```
<script type="text/plain">
This content has the media type plain/text, so characters reserved in HTML have no special meaning here: <div> ← this will be displayed.
</script>
```

(Note that the allowed content of the `script` element is [restricted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements), e.g. you [can’t](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#cdata-rcdata-restrictions) have `</script>` as text content (it would close the `script` element).)

Typically, `script` elements have `display:none` by default in browser’s CSS, so you’d need to overwrite that in your CSS, e.g.:

```
script[type="text/plain"] {display:block;}
```

Comment: This is really interesting, specially for rendering source code. Thank you for sharing this answer. Is this reliable? What are the limitations of this approach (besides what is documented in the link you've posted)?

Comment: Edit: Well, I've just found that this usage (using `<script>` to markup verbatim source code) is very impopular and unsupported from the perspective of Javascript code highlighters.

Answer (score 3):

The tag used to be `<XMP>` but in HTML 4 it was already deprecated. Browser's don't seem to have dropped its support but I would not recommend it for anything beyond quick debugging. The [MDN article about `<XMP>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/xmp) lists two other tags, `<plaintext>` and `<listing>`,  that were deprecated even earlier. I'm not aware of any current alternative.

Whatever, the code to encode plain text into HTML is pretty straightforward in most programming languages.

Note: the term *similar* means exactly that—all three are designed to inject plain text into HTML. I'm not implying that they are synonyms or that they behave identically—they don't.

Comment: There is no reason to expect browsers to drop support, partly because HTML5 requires continued support to `xmp` in browsers. The two other elements mentioned in the MDN article are *not* similar to `xmp` (and have hardly been used for a decade).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - Well, that's what the article says, *The `<plaintext>` and `<listing>` elements, similar to `<xmp>` but also obsolete.* <:-)

Comment: It says they are similar. They are not. The `plaintext` element has no end tag and always extends to the end of the document. The `listing` element was meant to be similar to `xmp`, but it was actually implemented like `pre`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function to escape the < >, eg:

```
'span.name': function(){
return this.name.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

Also take a look at `<plaintext></plaintext>`. I haven't used it myself but it is known to render everything that follows as plain text(by everything i mean to say it ignores the closing tag, so all the following code is rendered as text)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, so I voted it back up. The javascript is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific tag except the deprecated `<xmp>`.
But a script tag is allowed to store unformatted data.

Here is the only solution so far showing **dynamic** content, as you wanted.
Run code snippet for more info.

```html
<script id="myMagicTag" type="text/plain" style="display:block;">
      <b>Hello</b> World
</script>

Use <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143580/when-should-script-tags-be-visible-and-why-can-they">Visible</a> <a href="https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#data-block">Data-blocks</a>

<script>
      document.querySelector("#myMagicTag").innerHTML = "<b>Unformatted</b> dynamic content"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, you need to HtmlEncode it.

If your using a server-side language, that's not really difficult though.

In .NET you would do something like this:

```
string encodedtext = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(plaintext);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I need to prevent HTML from rendering

```
"if (a<b || c>100) ..."
```

and

```
"cout << ...".
```

Also the entire C++ code region HTML must pass through the GCC compiler with the desired effect.  I've hit on two schemes:

First:

```
//<xmp>
#include <string>
//</xmp>}
```

For reasons that escape me, the `<xmp>` tag is deprecated.  I find (2016-01-09) that Chrome and FF, at least, render the tag the way I want.  While researching my problem, I saw a remark that <xmp> is required in HTML 5.

Second, in `<head> ... </head>`, insert:

```
<style type="text/css">
    textarea { border: none; }
</style>
```

Then in `<body> ... </body>`, write:

```
//<br />  <textarea rows="4" disabled cols="80">
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//</textarea>  <br />
```

Note: Set `"cols="80"` to prevent following text from appearing on the right. Set `"rows=..."` to one more line than you enclose in the tag. This prevents scroll bars. This second technique has several disadvantages:

- The "disabled" attribute shades the region
- Incomprehensible, complex comments in the code sent to the compiler
- Harder to understand
- More typing

However, this methhod is neither obsolete nor deprecated.  The gods of HTML will make their faces to shine unto you.

Comment: To address your question about why xmp is deprecated, there is this remark in the [HTML3 DTD](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/html3.dtd):   " -- The XMP, LISTING and PLAINTEXT tags are incompatible with SGML
           and derive from very early versions of HTML. They require non-
           standard parsers and will cause problems for processing
           documents with standard SGML tools.
        --"

Comment: I don't know how many people write SGML but I'd guess HTML predominates.  Maybe the SGML spec should be mod'ed.  After all, in-band signalling systems always need escape sequences.  Many mark-up languages use "\n\n" to cause a 'new paragraph' action.