# CSS: style is reset after `<pre>` element

Tags: html, css

There is web-site for Nodeclipse FOSS project http://www.nodeclipse.org/

I am not quick at web development and styles, and there is problem I don't know how to approach:

On the main page http://www.nodeclipse.org/index.html there is `<pre>` element ([source line](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/www.nodeclipse.org/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L207))
and after it style is always different than at pragraph start.

[image: example]

I guess there's something to be in applied http://www.nodeclipse.org/pipe.css" ([source](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/www.nodeclipse.org/blob/gh-pages/pipe.css)), but what to look for? (As it is not about `pre` element but what happens after it)

FOSS project needs help with web.

Comment: I noticed that the next lines after the closing `</pre>` are not wraped in `<p></p>` tags

Comment: its because they have font:18 for .interior.. and they are using <p> everywhere but after pre they were not.. there is some empty <p> tags after that text

Comment: This is one paragraph, one news, so I used one `<p> </p>` pair. And `<pre>` is inside... So what HTML tags should be there? What is usual for such case?

Comment: no, if you see the rendered HTML<p> tag was closed before <pre>..<pre> is not inside <p> :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, `<pre>` tag usage inside `<p>` tag breaks the DOM structure

[image]

So the text after `pre` tag are not enclosed inside the `<p>` tag.

> It is not advised to use `pre` tag to display a content that doesn't lose it's meaning if not pre-formatted.

So use a `<a>` tag or some other suitable tags like `span` (if you don't want it to be a clickable link) to display the url and style it accordingly.

Comment: That is nice hint. The link inside `pre` is Eclipse update site, that is not to be clicked but copy-paste in Eclipse Help->Install New Software,  
If using `code`, then I would need to add line breaks before and after. (I need to have this link as one separate line for easier copying)

Comment: I looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets but don't know how to format those links or short code snippets to be on separate not wrapped line...

Comment: @PaulVerest If you don't want to use line-breaks, use a code tag and in css set it's display type to block

Comment: OK, but some code should be inside line, not starting on new...
Is adding `<br>` the only way?

Comment: @PaulVerest Use different class names and set display:block only to the class which you need to start on a new line. If you don't know how to do this, refer http://www.tizag.com/cssT/class.php