# html - Display new line in code tag

Tags: html

I'm trying to display code but everything is showed in one line. How can I display multiline code tag?

This is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<title>Documentación: Events</title>
<body>
<code>
    {
    "id_tabla":3,
    "fecha":"02-09-2015",
    "privacidad":0,
    "timediff_m": "00"
    }
</code>
</body>
```

And this is how is showed in browser:

```
{"id_tabla":3,"fecha":"02-09-2015","privacidad":0,"timediff_m": "00"}
```

## Edit

I can only use `<code>` tag

Comment: You could use the `<pre>` tag instead. [See this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31775545/1125161):

```css
code {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre-wrap   
}
```

```html
<code>
    {
    "id_tabla":3,
    "fecha":"02-09-2015",
    "privacidad":0,
    "timediff_m": "00"
    }
</code>
```

Answer (score 59):

Use `<pre>` instead of `<code>`.

```html
<pre>
  {
    "id_tabla": 3,
    "fecha": "02-09-2015",
    "privacidad": 0,
    "timediff_m": "00"
  }
</pre>
```

You should use `<code>` if you want to have something inline and `<pre>` when you need something multiline.

Comment: "The <pre> tag defines preformatted text... Text in a <pre> element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks." This means you can apply different CSS to each.