# How to show <tag> in the browser?

Tags: html, css

Actually I need to a `div` (an environment like IDE) for showing some code. exactly like stackoverflow when I write 4 space in back of the line:

```
Now I can see tags <span>, <p>, <div>, etc ... in the browser
```

Anyway, how can I print a `<tag>` in the screen? *(without translating by browser)*

In other word, how can I see `<span>` in the output in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnmwjd76/)?

Comment: In an IDE, you would click on "Source". I'm not sure I understand what you want.

Comment: @MrLister no no, I just want to `print('<div>')` in the page, when I do that, browser will translates it and I can not see it ...

Comment: If you load a text file (that is, not an HTML file) into a browser, it will be displayed as plain text.

Comment: Why don't you want to encode the text?

Comment: @MrLister actually my website is about programming, and I need to print some code in the page, but when I write them in the HTML code, user can not see it, because they will be translate. look at stackoverflow, when I write a tag between two ` quotes, the tag will show in the page (and its backgrond will be gray). how can I do that ?

Comment: @PaulKienitz I think you don't know what I want ... look, please give me a fiddle, and show a tag like `<span>`  in the output

Comment: Just translate the <s to &lt;s and >s to &gt;s, and don't try to fight the browser.

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text to appear "code like" you should put it in a `<pre>` tag. However, to use characters that are specific to the language you are using, you can use HTML character codes as seen [here](http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/htmlchars.html).

For instance to write a div tag and have it show up without being rendered you could write `&lt;div&gt;`. This will show as `<div>` in the browser.

`&lt;` will be rendered as `<`, and `&gt;` will be rendered as `>`.

Most code editors can do this for you if you don't want to spend the time changing each character to it's respective code. For instance, I use WebStorm and there is a plugin called "String Manipulator" that will change as much code as I want with one click of a button.

Comment: Thanks buddy, just using something like `&lt;div&gt;` is a standard thing? for example stackoverflow uses what approach for appear code?

Comment: It's standard and most web programming languages provide a built in way to do it.

Comment: That, I'm not so sure about, but I would bet not. Taking a look around now to see if there is a better option. Edit: What Paul said makes sense though. @stack

Answer (score 3):

You should use the HTML Entities of html:

[W3C School Html Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

To do that, you'll have to use the special character codes < (less than) and > greater than. So your code will look lile:

```
<span>&lt;tag&gt;</span>
```

The result of this will be:

```
<tag>
```