# How to get code as plain text

Tags: html

```
<pre>
    <button>323</button> // I see button
</pre>

<code>
     <button>323</button>  // I see button
</code>
```

How can I show the code, i.e. plain text in browser ?

And what is then, generally speaking, the purpose of `code` and `pre` tags at all ?

Comment: Ctrl + U (on windows)?

Comment: @Vucko, I need the code in the main window, because the code is part of a lesson.

Comment: I see your answers and can't believe that there is no a simple tag for this purpose. Ands what is than the purpose of `pre` and `code` tag at all ?

Comment: @bonaca `code` elements are used to represent code (and are generally inline elements). `<pre>` elements will preserve any spacing you have (including whitespace).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML tags as plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817262/how-to-display-html-tags-as-plain-text)

Comment: @BenM, you say: `code` elements are used to represent code - but why it does not doing that?

Comment: @bonaca It does, you just need to escape tag literals so they're not interpreted by the browser as child nodes. It's a semantic tag.

Comment: @BenM, excuse me, but it is obvious that it is not working. If a tag needs something extra to make it work, then ...

Comment: *...obvious it is not working*?! You'd better contact the W3C then, or your browser manufacturer. The issue you're encountering isn't a problem with the implementation of `<code>` by your browser... That's like asking why parent nodes with floated children aren't self-clearing in 2015! Why should I have to add extra CSS to make it work?!

Comment: @BenM, maybe you're right. But I still think html is stupid here. In any case, thanks a lot. You helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use HTML entities (i.e. replacing `<` with `&lt;` and `<` with `&gt;`) as follows:

```html
<code>
    &lt;button&gt;323&lt;/button&gt;
</code>
```

And similarly using `<pre>`:

```html
<pre>
    &lt;button&gt;323&lt;/button&gt;
</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>` respectively, for the code that should be displayed in the browser. These are called `HTML entities` as @BenM mentioned.

Here is a list of all HTML entities: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

***Checkout this working example:***

```html
<pre>
    &lt;button&gt;323&lt;/button&gt;
</pre>

<code>
     &lt;button&gt;323&lt;/button&gt;
</code>
```

Note that `<pre>` keeps the indent while `<code>` doesnt.

Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/everything-need-know-html-pre-element/

---

Should you be using `<pre>` or `<code>` or something else?

Readup: [<code> vs <pre> vs <samp> for inline and block code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets)

Answer (score 1):

Either the `<code>` tag or the `<pre>` tag works here, but you need to use codes to get the proper glyphs. Using `<pre>` will keep your formatting (i.e. the spaces in front).

```
<code>
    &lt;button&gt;323&lt;/button&gt;
</code>
```

or

```
<pre>
    &lt;button&gt;323&lt;/button&gt;
</pre>
```

Details:

`&lt;` gives the `<`

`&gt;` gives the `>`

Comment: There's no need to wrap `<code>` inside of `<pre>`.

Comment: If he wants to keep his indent, I think we need it. Just using the code tags eats the spaces he's got in front there.

Comment: 1. Where does the OP says the indent needs to be retained? 2. `<pre>` alone will do that.

Comment: His example asks how to show `        <button>323</button>` with spaces in it, so I put in the `<pre>` to keep them. Just seemed to be sticking with his exact example.

Comment: It's like one line from his code, which has spaces in it. I even explain that my example has `<pre>` just to keep his formatting.

Comment: of course I can see the space, but how do you know that's not just an indent to better format the code?

Comment: Right, and if he wants to keep that indent, then this is how.

Comment: Correct, but then there's no need to add `<code>` inside of the `<pre>`

Comment: If I just use `<code>` tags in Firefox, the spaces disappear. Am I missing something?

Comment: You have a `<code>` element inside of your `<pre>` element, which isn't necessary. Please see my answer, which shows the `<pre>` tag alone preserving the whitespace without any requirement to add a child node of `code`.

Comment: HAHAHAH I get it now, sorry for being such a dummy. I figured I was missing something, but I couldn't figure out what. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using `textarea` element with `disabled` attribute set to `true`

```css
textarea:disabled {
  min-width:200px;
  max-width:200px;
  min-height:50px;
  max-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<textarea disabled="true">
  <button>323</button>
</textarea>
```

Comment: @BenM Not certain about meaning of semantic , at present Question ?

Comment: You must have heard of the semantic web? http://www.w3.org/standards/semanticweb/

Comment: Also, not sure if OP wants to see the textarea. Maybe hide the borders?

Comment: @BenM Yes. Not certain how applicable to present Question ? , possible solution at post ? Appear capable of being parsed by a consumer of semantic data ?

Comment: @RahulDesai Did not adjust border or background ; appeared OP expected  `<code>` type display ? , using `html` tags

Comment: @BenM Curious how approach at solution would be considered _"not very semantic? "_ ?

Comment: Because textareas are for displaying or entering user input, not displaying code.

Comment: @BenM _"Because textareas are for displaying or entering user input, not displaying code."_ ? Link to documentation , specification where `textarea` should only be used for user input ; and `textarea` should not be used for displaying "code" ?