# how get insterted data from mysql as it inserted

Tags: java, mysql

i have built quiz web project. 
i want to insert below mentioned test question into database. i am writing  this question in html textarea, then getdata from html with inner.html :

[image]

but when  i select this question from database it looks like that, it is hard readable, carelessly written:

[image]

help me make  above mentioned tests readable.

my sql insert  code :

```
 public void addtest(TestModel test) throws Exception {
    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
 String sql = "INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (QUESTION,A,B,C,D,E,QUESTION_TYPE,SCORE,SUBJECT, CORRECT, Variant) " +
                 " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";

    try {

        c= DbHelper.getConnection();
        if(c != null) {
            ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1,test.getQuestion());
            ps.setString(2,test.getOptionA());
            ps.setString(3,test.getOptionB());
            ps.setString(4,test.getOptionC());
            ps.setString(5,test.getOptionD());
            ps.setString(6,test.getOptionE());
            ps.setString(7,test.getQuestionType());
            ps.setLong(8,test.getScore());
            ps.setLong(9,test.getSubjectId());
            ps.setString(10,test.getCorrectOption());
            ps.setInt(11,test.getVariant());


            ps.execute();

        }  else {
            System.out.println("Connection is null");
        }
    }  catch (Exception ex)  {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    }  finally {

        JdbcUtility.close(c,ps,null);
    }

}
```

my sql select code :

```
     public TestModel getquestionlist(long firstpage,int variant) throws Exception {
    TestModel testdata = new TestModel();

    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String sql =" SELECT  TE.ID,TE.QUESTION,TE.A,TE.B,TE.C,TE.D,TE.E,TE.F,TE.G,TE.QUESTION_TYPE,TE.SCORE,S.NAME as Subject,TE.CREATE_DAY,TE.CORRECT, d.value, TE.Variant FROM TEST_TABLE TE " +
            "INNER JOIN SUBJECT S ON  S.ID = TE.SUBJECT " +
            "inner join dictionary d on d.ID = TE.Variant " +
            "WHERE TE.ACTIVE =1 AND S.ACTIVE =1 AND TE.Variant = ? " +
            "LIMIT ?,1; ";

    try {

        c = DbHelper.getConnection();

        if (c != null) {

            ps = c.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1,variant);
            ps.setLong(2,  firstpage);

            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {

                testdata.setId(rs.getLong("ID"));
                testdata.setQuestion(rs.getString("QUESTION"));
                testdata.setOptionA(rs.getString("A"));
                testdata.setOptionB(rs.getString("B"));
                testdata.setOptionC(rs.getString("C"));
                testdata.setOptionD(rs.getString("D"));
                testdata.setOptionE(rs.getString("E"));
                testdata.setOptionF(rs.getString("F"));
                testdata.setOptionG(rs.getString("G"));
                testdata.setQuestionType(rs.getString("QUESTION_TYPE"));
                testdata.setScore(rs.getLong("SCORE"));
                testdata.setTestSubject(rs.getString("Subject"));
                testdata.setCreateDate(rs.getDate("CREATE_DAY"));
                testdata.setCorrectOption(rs.getString("CORRECT"));
                testdata.setVariant(rs.getInt("Variant"));

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        JdbcUtility.close(c, ps, rs);
    }

    return testdata;
}
```

Comment: mmm, your question is not clear can you explain more?

Comment: i have add 2 pictures:  first  picture describe question- i have capured from pdf file. the second picture i have captured from my web application when i select  test question from datase.  i want   to describe test question in my web application as it was in pdf file.

Comment: You are probably looking for html `<pre>`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets for example

Comment: This looks like it has to do with the view you are rendering as a web page, not an SQL issue. You appear to be just dumping the `toString()` of a `TestModel` on the page.  Post your HTML (or JSP or whatever) that deals with the returned `TestModel`

Comment: <code> </code>  and <br>  worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<br/>` to break line :

```
"1: public class WaterBottle { <br/>"
```

So in the moment of getting the result you can concatenate your result with `<br/>` for example :

```
testdata.setQuestion(rs.getString("QUESTION") + "<br/>");
```