# Show Angular code and HTML in an Angular page (not parsed)

Tags: angular

I want to show some example Angular code and HTML in my angular page, but whatever I do, Angular tries to parse it.

I've tried in `<code>`, in `<pre>` and even this:
`&lt;div class="name">&#123;&#123; name &#125;&#125; &lt;/div>`

but even then it tries to bind to 'name'.

I don't want to do it via any binding, I just want to type the HTML in the components HTML page.

Maybe a better example: when I paste this text in the HTML, I still get an input element, I just want to show the HTML (from input to box.value).

`<pre><code><input #box (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box.value)"></code></pre>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets ?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a variable in the component file

```
public htmlSnippt = `<input #box (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box.value)">`;
```

Then use it in the html

```
<pre>
   {{htmlSnippt}}
</pre>
```

in XHTML you can use CDATA

```
<![CDATA[<input #box (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box.value)">]]>
```

Comment: Is there also a way that I can type it directlly in the HTML?

Comment: Nice, this works in a <pre> but then I loose the code formatting. When I put it in <code> it shows the code formatting but I loose the HTML tags....

Comment: you can CDATA as pure XHTML afaik, check the answer again @Michel

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<pre>
  <code [innerHTML]="someCode"></code>
</pre>
```

Component:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  someCode = 'export model = new Model({
     a:function(){}
     b:4
  })'
}
```

**Update to properly should html tags**

```
<pre>
  <code>{{someCode}}</code>
</pre>

<pre>
  <code>{{someOtherCode}}</code>
</pre>
```

Component

```
export class SomeComponent  {
  someCode = 'export model = new Model({a:function(){}b:4})'
  someOtherCode = '<div>some html</div>'
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work when I add a <DIV> tag in the code.

Comment: Now it works even with html tags. See updated answer