# CSS: add background color to inline <pre> text

Tags: html, css

How do I get the gray background color as in `this word` which is inside an inline `<pre></pre>`?

Here is what I have done. From the code snippet, inline seems to be fine after the `</pre>` but not before `<pre>`.

```css
pre.inline {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #80b3FF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px
}
```

```html
<p>We use <pre class="inline">model</pre> to specify the statistical model.</p>
```

Comment: You should check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets) first. You should probably use `code` as inline instead of `pre`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other way to solve the problem using 'div' and 'span'

```
    .inline {
    background-color: #80b3FF;
    border-radius: 4px;    padding: 3px
}
```

`<div>We use <span class="inline">model</span>` to specify the statistical model.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the result of the pre tag creating the new line despite being inline display. it works as expected if you change it to a span instead:

```css
span{
    background-color: #80b3FF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px
}
```

```html
<p>We use <span>model</span> to specify the statistical model.</p>
```

Or Code if you want the monospace font by default:

```css
code{
    background-color: #80b3FF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px
}
```

```html
<p>We use <code>model</code> to specify the statistical model.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because　`pre` is not a phrasing content . See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852312/list-of-html5-elements-that-can-be-nested-inside-p-element) Use div instead.

```css
pre.inline {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #80b3FF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px
}
```

```html
<div>We use <pre class="inline">model</pre> to specify the statistical model.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is an image of what is rendered in browser with your code. And this pretty much explains the issue you are facing.

[image]

In  order to solve this below are few ways. Use `<div>` instead of a `<p>`

```css
pre.inline {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #80b3FF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px
}
```

```html
<div>We use <pre class="inline">model</pre> to specify the statistical model.</div>
```

Use `<code>` instead of `<pre>`

```css
code.inline {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #80b3FF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p>We use <code class="inline">model</code> to specify the statistical model.</p>
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets) will help you understand a bit more about `<code>` and `<pre>`

And [this link](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-p-element) more about `<p>` element