# How do I display the text with all of the tabs and new lines (\t and \n) in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, types

I have a variable 'messages' of type array and whenever I put it into the terminal it has tabs and new lines but whenever I save messages to a variable and display it on my rails application, it no longer has these. How do I fix this so it shows the new lines and tabs on the rails app.

Code for outputting to the terminal in model (User):

```
   def runMessages
     messages << stdout.read
     messages << stderr.read
     puts "OUTPUT IS:" + messages[0]
     messages
   end
```

Code in controller for saving to variable:

```
   messages = @user.runMessages
   @user.output = messages[0]
```

Code in views:

```
    <p> <%= @user.output %> </p>
```

In the terminal it looks something like this:

```
    Beginning run ...
    Done.
```

While on the application it looks like this:

```
Beginning run...Done.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [HTML `<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag.

```
<pre> <%= @user.output %> </pre>
```

You could also use it in combination with the `<code>` tag, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets) for the difference.