# How can I add programming code to my website similar to what appears in any text editor or stackoverflow?

Tags: html, css, sass

eg python code

```
import  os

def main:
    print("Hello, Stackers")
```

[To be shown as this image in webpage][1]

Is there any template that does the styling for itself?

Note: I know how to use pre and code tags also checked Wordpress, So anything other than that.
Thankyou for answers.

Comment: If you use the '<SCRIPT>' and '</SCRIPT>' opening and closing HTML tags, you can insert Javascript code on one of your webpages between those two tags. You can set one of the '<SCRIPT>' tag's attributes in order to specify the particular programming language you want to use, but if you leave it out, the browser will probably automatically interpret it as Javascript. There should be Javascript code samples on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thankyou for your answer learnt something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like you said without syntax highlighting using `<code>`, `<pre>` or `<samp>`, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4611735/12731997) for the explanation of them. However, if you want some fancy colors, you have to use a js library. Some nice ones I've found:

[highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)

[Prism.js](https://prismjs.com/)

[SHJS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/)

[Rainbow](http://rainbowco.de/)

Note: all of these are not live - means edits of the code would break the highlighting. As example for an editor [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) is a good solution.

I hope I could help you. Have a nice day :)