# Array of Objects are not printing

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Output:

[image]

My code:

```js
let carsArray = [
  {
    make: "BMW",
    model: "325i",
    year: 2034,
  },
  {
    make: "Volvo",
    model: "540xi",
    year: 2025,
  },
  {
    make: "BMW",
    model: "435e",
    year: 1994,
  },
  {
    make: "BMW",
    model: "X6",
    year: 2025,
  },
];

function twoYearsOld (element) {
  let year = element.year - 2023;
  return year === 2;
};

let twoYearOldCars = carsArray.filter(twoYearsOld);
document.write(twoYearOldCars);
```

Hey Everyone. I have an issue where when I write `document.write`, the outcome on the live page just says object, object. I have an array with objects in it.

I am expecting it to say this:

```
[
  { 
    make: 'Volvo', 
    model: '540xi', 
    year: 2025 
  },
  { 
    make: 'BMW', 
    model: 'X6', 
    year: 2025 
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you are using a wrong method to display your result. you can use **console.log()** or **JSON.stringify()** like this

1. With **Console.log**

   console.log(twoYearOldCars);
2. With **JSON.stringify()**

   document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(twoYearOldCars);

Now let see how the code looks

```
let carsArray = [
    {
      make: "BMW",
      model: "325i",
      year: 2034,
    },
    {
      make: "Volvo",
      model: "540xi",
      year: 2025,
    },
    {
      make: "BMW",
      model: "435e",
      year: 1994,
    },
    {
      make: "BMW",
      model: "X6",
      year: 2025,
    },
  ];

  function twoYearsOld (element) {
    let year = element.year - 2023;
    return year === 2;
  };

let twoYearOldCars = carsArray.filter(twoYearsOld);

console.log(JSON.stringify(twoYearOldCars));
```

Comment: Hey Thank you for the help. I wrote this and it worked out.  "document.write(JSON.stringify(twoYearOldCars));"

Comment: Also How come using document.write is the wrong method?

Comment: By using Document.write(), you don't have the hand of where the content is being inserted. Javascript will insert it as last node of Document Object. You must be clear when you write your code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to "prettify" the data. You can [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) it, and then add it to a `<code>` element inside a `<pre>` element. [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611591/code-vs-pre-vs-samp-for-inline-and-block-code-snippets) | [ref2](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element).

```js
let carsArray=[{make:"BMW",model:"325i",year:2034},{make:"Volvo",model:"540xi",year:2025},{make:"BMW",model:"435e",year:1994},{make:"BMW",model:"X6",year:2025}];

function twoYearsOld(element) {
  return element.year - 2023 === 2;
}

const twoYearOldCars = carsArray.filter(twoYearsOld);

const code = document.querySelector('code');

// `stringify` accepts three arguments. The first is the data
// you want to stringify, the third is the space indentation.
// and the second is "the replacer" - you can read about
// that in the documentaton
code.textContent = JSON.stringify(twoYearOldCars, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre><code></code></pre>
```